# ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 1161

Tags: oracle, ora-12012

Here is my code.

```
update netz98.order_data
set usergroup = 'DISTR'
where 
modelcode||optcode||interiortrimcode in ('CW1WXJXFZLAA6016E','CW7WXMXFZLAA6014E')
and committed = 0
;
commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

[ORA-12012](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e9858.htm#sthref2652) is always followed by a list of error codes/descriptions causing the failure.  What you must do is to check your log files and by the errors next to the 12012 itself you will realize what's going on.

The error is not necessarily related with the sentences the JOB is running, so the provided code not necessarily tell the cause, as stated by the referenced documentation:

> ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job string
> Cause: An error was caught while doing an automatic execution of a job.
> Action: **Look at the accompanying errors for details on why the execute failed.**

Emphasis is mine.